# Comparing Two Files For Matching Words in Linux

Tags: linux, command, grep

Lets say we have two files as follows

### File A.txt

Karthick is not so intelligent
He is not lazy

### File B.txt

karthick is not so bad either
He is hard worker

so in the two files above, the commone words are "karthick is not so" & "He is" in each of the lines. Is there any way to print all such common lines with either grep command or some linux command?

Comment: you can try diff, but it's match line, not word

Comment: You can find the intersection of two files with either `grep -f file1 file2` or `comm -12 file1 file2`. Note that both commands require each word to be on a separate line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the **dwdiff** utility :).

Example usage:

```
dwdiff "File A.txt" "File B.txt"
```

It might take a little while to get used to it's output, but check http://linux.die.net/man/1/dwdiff for more details on that.

There are also several visual diff applications out there, but I prefer using it on the command line.